# Lambda on AutoMapper Initialization Shows Warning as Function but Fine as Sub

Tags: vb.net, lambda, automapper-6

I updated an AutoMapper V3.3.1 to V6.1.1 and much to my surprise, after putting all CreateMaps() in a profile, it actually worked perfectly right out of the gate – almost scary for me.

The problem that I am having is that it IS working with the code below as is suggested in the AutoMapper documentation:

```
Private Sub InitiatizeAutoMapper()
    Mapper.Initialize(Function(cfg)
                          cfg.AddProfile(Of MappingProfile)()
                      End Function)
End Sub
```

But the code issues a warning:

```
Warning BC42105 Function '<anonymous method>' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used.
```

If I add a Return to the Lambda like:

```
Private Sub InitiatizeAutoMapper()
    Mapper.Initialize(Function(cfg)
                          Return cfg.AddProfile(Of MappingProfile)()
                      End Function)
End Sub
```

I then get the following error:

```
Error   BC30518 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Initialize' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Shared Overloads Sub Initialize(config As Action(Of IMapperConfigurationExpression))': Expression does not produce a value.
    'Public Shared Overloads Sub Initialize(config As Action(Of IMapperConfigurationExpression))': Expression does not produce a value.
    'Public Shared Overloads Sub Initialize(config As MapperConfigurationExpression)': Lambda expression cannot be converted to 'MapperConfigurationExpression' because 'MapperConfigurationExpression' is not a delegate type.
```

**Now - if I make it a Sub instead of a function, it all works well with no errors like this:**

```
Private Sub InitiatizeAutoMapper()
    Mapper.Initialize(Sub(cfg)
                          cfg.AddProfile(Of MappingProfile)()
                      End Sub)
End Sub
```

I know that this will probably be a head-slapper but I am trying to follow the documentation and am afraid to release this into production in that I might be missing something.

**EDIT:**

I chose to break down the multiline lambda to make it a little easier for me, which also avails IntelliSense options quite handily for future enhancement. While it is probably not the "coolest" code, I find it very readable.

```
Private Sub InitiatizeAutoMapper()
    Dim config As New Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression : With config
        .AddProfile(Of MappingProfile)()
    End With
    Mapper.Initialize(config)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @jmcilhinney for your reply. Of course I know the difference between a Sub and a Function, and I guess that I've only been exposed previously to Function Delegates so I will have to brush up a bit on Action Delegates which now makes perfect sense. It was the end of a long day and I guess that I wasn't able to see the forest for the trees. I was converting C# to VB as well from https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Static-and-Instance-API and I guess nothing was sinking in. I've edited my OP to show the course I took. Seriously though - thanks for your direction.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a `Function` is that it returns something. In your first code snippet, what is your anonymous function returning?  It isn't returning anything because it has no `Return` statement.   There's no point arbitrarily adding a `Return` statement if you don't actually have anything to return and you can't return the result of `AddProfile` if that doesn't return anything itself.  Basically, your lambda doesn't return anything and what do we call a method that doesn't return anything?  It's a `Sub`.

You'll notice in the error message you posted that the `Initialize` method overloads that take a delegate as an argument are expecting an `Action`, not a `Func`.  `Action` delegates are created with a `Sub` while a `Function` is used to create a `Func` delegate.